# Using getopt to parse second argument into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, getopt

How do I parse the second argument into a variable using `bash` and `getopt` on the following script.

I can do `sh test.sh -u` and get "userENT" to display. But if I do `sh test.sh -u testuser` on this script I get an error.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Now check for arguments
OPTS=`getopt -o upbdhrstv: --long username,password,docker-build,help,version,\
  release,remote-registry,stage,develop,target: -n 'parse-options' -- "$@"`



while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -u | --username) 
            case "$2" in
               *) API_KEY_ART_USER="$2"; echo "userENT" ;shift ;;
            esac ;;
    -- ) shift; break ;;
    * ) if [ _$1 != "_" ]; then ERROR=true; echo; echo "Invalid option $1"; fi; break ;;

   esac
done
echo "user" $API_KEY_ART_USER
```

How can I pass the `-u testuser` and not have an `Invalid option testuser` error?

Output:

```
>sh test3.sh -u testuser
userENT

Invalid option testuser
user testuser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man getopt` would tell you that a colon following the option indicates that it has an argument. You only have a colon after the v. You also weren't `shift`ing within your loop, so you'd be unable to parse any options past the first one. And I'm not sure why you felt the need to have a second `case` statement that only had a single default option. In addition, there were a number of poor practices in your code including use of all caps variable names and backticks instead of `$()` for executing commands. And you've tagged your question [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) but your shebang is `/bin/sh`. Give this a try, but you shouldn't be using code without understanding what it does.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Now check for arguments
opts=$(getopt -o u:pbdhrstv: --long username:,password,docker-build,help,version,\
    release,remote-registry,stage,develop,target: -n 'parse-options' -- "$@")

while true; do
    case "$1" in
    -u|--username)
        shift
        api_key_art_user="$1"
        echo "userENT"
    ;;
    --)
        shift;
        break
    ;;
    *)
        if [ -n "$1" ]; then 
            err=true
            echo "Invalid option $1"
        fi
        break
    ;;
    esac
    shift
done
echo "user $api_key_art_user"
```

Comment: Should also actually use the output of `getopt` (`eval set -- "$opts"`).